# Types of char in C++ (confused by C++ primer explanation)

Tags: c++, char

The book states the following:

> Unlike the other integer types, there are three distinct basic character types: char, signed char, and unsigned char. In particular, char is not the same type as signed char. Although there are three character types, there are only two representations: signed and unsigned. The (plain) char type uses one of these representations. Which of the other two character representations is equivalent to char depends on the compiler.

This description is confusing. It says that char is not the same as signed char, but then says it uses "one of the two representations: signed and unsigned."

It also states that there are only "2 representations," but three actual types. What is this saying exactly?

Comment: Very short summary: when using `char`, you don't know whether it values are form -128 to 127 or from 0 to 255, the compiler is free to choose. The ranges are defined in 'signed char` and `unsigned char`. More information in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an integer type is signed it means that it holds negative and positive values and the value `0`.

If an integer type is unsigned it means that it holds positive values and the value `0`. It cannot hold negative values.

Some types have "more names". E.g. `long`, `long int` and `signed long int` are all names for the same type.

Let's see what is the case with most of the integer types. E.g. `int`  and `signed int` are the exact same type. These are two names for the same type. This type is signed (holds negative and positive values and the value `0`). `unsigned int` is a different type, it is unsigned, i.e. it only holds positive values and the value zero. This pattern repeats for all integer types (`short`, `long` etc)

The exception to this is `char`: `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` are 3 different types. `signed char` is signed, `unsigned char` is unsigned and `char` well it can be either signed or unsigned depending on the compiler and platform.

Now what does it mean that two types are different? For beginners it really doesn't make much of an impact. This fact comes more into play in function overloading and meta programming.

Answer (score 4):

This is trying to communicate that compilers are free to decide which interpretation they take, either signed or unsigned, and as a programmer you must understand that it might not be what you expect. If you're used to it being signed, another compiler might be unsigned, and your code might break because of that assumption.

As such, if you *need* signed or unsigned, use the appropriate keyword, or better, use something like `uint8_t` to make it abundantly clear what you want.

`int` and others are only `unsigned` if so specified. `char` is a bit of a loose cannon here.

Answer (score 2):

A representation determines how the bits in a memory region should be interpreted if we know it contains objects of a certain type.

For instance: on a platform where `int` and `float` are both 4 bytes long, a compiler would interpret the bits in a 4 byte word differently if it was declared to hold a `float` than if it were declared to hold an `int`. Both `int` and `float` are distinct types that impose some value representation (and interpretation) of bits. But those representations don't have to belong *just* to those types. If on our platform a `long int` was also 4 bytes long, then it would almost certainly have the same representation as an `int`, even though they are **distinct types**.

This is similar to the case the book is describing. There are *two* types, `singed char` and `unsgined char`. Each imposes its own representation (and interpretation) of the bits in its storage.

And next to those two types, there is another, third type, which is named plainly `char` and is not the same type as the other two (just like `long int` is not the same type as an `int`). However, it's the same size as both of the others, and has the same representation as one of them (which exactly is implementation defined).